# keylistener with jlist

Tags: java, swing, jlist, keylistener

want the jtextField in my frame to appear when press any key on the keyboard in the jList, this is what i did :

```
public class test extends javax.swing.JFrame {

 public test ()  {

 jTextField3.setVisible(false);
         .
         .
         .

private void jList1KeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {


    jTextField3.setVisible(true);
    System.out.print("Pressed");
  }
 }
}
```

when pressing any key , it prints "Pressed" but the text field doesn't appear, why??

Comment: Paste your full (relevant) code. Looks like the field is `setVisible` before even the event is fired.

Comment: @DavidKroukamp i tried revalidate() , and it works . THANKS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try calling `revalidate()`/`repaint()` on your `JFrame`s instance.